# how to compile an .m file which contains calling of another .exe file inside it

Tags: matlab-deployment

I have an .m file from which I call another .exe file on my machine with "system" statement. Now, I am going to use "deploytool" to create a console application. But, running this application couldn't run the .exe file inside it. Please tell me if there is any way to resolve this problem.

More detail:
These are the files which are used by main m.file: A.txt , B.xlsx, C.exe (I have put all of them in a folder). And this is part of m.file which utilizes these file:
 1- m = xlsread('B.xls');
 … 
12- [status,cmdout] = system('C'); 
After running C.exe it should output a text file called “Out.txt” and then
 … 
13- fileID = fopen(‘Out.txt’);
14- links = textscan(fileID, ‘%s’, 7, ‘delimiter’, ‘,’);
 … 
But in the resulted standalone file when it reaches to line 12, can’t run C.exe! –

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to show some codes and where you stuck

Comment: you should add these to your post not here